# Integrity error when Google users try to connect (old users)

Tags: django, python-social-auth

We have `django-social-auth` used to enable Google sign-ins in our app. People with recently created Google account can effectively connect while older can’t – I get an IntegrityError.

I have no idea how that Google OAuth truly works on the Google side, but I don’t get why it would change from users to others. We have three backends activated (GoogleOAuth, GoogleOAuth2, GoogleOpenID). And I can’t find the documentation for that IntegrityError. We’re using django.

Any idea?

EDIT: error as requested

`pgpool: 2016-04-07 10:33:13 LOG:   pid 27330: pool_send_and_wait: Error or notice message from backend: : DB node id: 0 backend pid: 3539 statement: INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_superuser", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "is_staff", "is_active", "date_joined") VALUES ('!', '2016-04-07 08:33:13.123859+00:00', false, '**************', '', '', '****************@gmail.com', false, true, '2016-04-07 08:33:13.123859+00:00') RETURNING "auth_user"."id" message: la valeur d'une clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « auth_user_email_key »`

Comment: can you paste traceback of the error?

Comment: Yep, see the edited question.